# Remove groups with more than one unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have an excel like

```
Name   X    Y
A      5    9
B      5    10
C      7    9
D      7    9
E      5    10
F      5    8
```

I want to remove rows that have duplicate values in Y column but different values in X column. (In other words if there are more than one values of X for one value of Y, delete all those rows)
Result should be:

```
Name   X    Y
B      5    10
E      5    10
F      5    8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and `"nunique"`, and filter out groups with more than 1 unique value in X:

```
df[df.groupby('Y').X.transform('nunique') == 1]

  Name  X   Y
1    B  5  10
4    E  5  10
5    F  5   8
```

Similar solution, use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to broadcast the result:

```
df[df.Y.map(df.groupby('Y').X.nunique()) == 1]

  Name  X   Y
1    B  5  10
4    E  5  10
5    F  5   8
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: @AmanGarg You're welcome. Next time, I would suggest also adding what you've tried in the OP to avoid potential downvote vultures.